# Слово "толькочтошний"

Tags: словообразование

Допустим ли в разговорной речи такой неологизм ***"толькочтошний"***?

Comment: Человек дотошный напишет "толькочтошный"!

Comment: Не понял... _+(*)+_

Comment: Мне почему-то кажется что "ый" в конце смотрится (или слышится) лучше. Но это, видимо, субъективно.

Comment: Всё-таки это действительно правда, что почти все прилагательные с временным значением оканчиваются на НИЙ, а не на НЫЙ. Поэтому для меня естественнее сказать с И, чтобы не воспринималось это слово по-другому, не казалось похожим по смыслу на "пустяшный" и другие.

Comment: Я понимаю намек на "сегодняшний", но не согласен, что И является каким-то свойством временных прилагательных (см "месячный", "недельный", итд). Мне кажется гораздо более важным тот факт, что на сочетании "oчний/ошний" (с ударением на О) у меня ломается язык. Других примеров такого сочетания я найти не смог (очевидно потому что не только у меня язык ломается), тогда как "очный/ошный" - сколько хочешь.

Comment: И правда, их мало, но есть ещё *тамошний* и *тутошний*. Хотя с логикой Вашей действительно стоит считаться. :)

Comment: *тамошний* и *тутошний* - это другое, там ударение не туда.

Comment: А-а, да, точно, не подумал.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У меня в обиходе неологизмы на каждом шагу; главное - всем всё понятно!

***Толькочтошний*** пишется слитно.

Comment: Спасибо, Галина! Тогда уберу второй вопрос и в первом напишу слитно, чтобы не резала глаза собственная ошибка. :)